# ways to arrange positive integers from 1 to 100 on a circle

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can the positive integers from 1 to 100 be arranged in a circle such that the
sum of every two integers placed opposite each other is the same? (Arrangements that are rotations
of each other count as the same.) Express your answer in the form a! · b^c
.

Comment: First figure out what the sum of opposite numbers must be. Can you do that?

Comment: its obviously 101 i think

Comment: Now how many pairs are there?

Comment: there are 50 pairs

Comment: Good. A hint: how many ways to order 50 objects. Another hint: a pair can be flipped either one way or another.

Comment: i suppose there are 50! ways to arrange numbers on half a circle but i am actually stuck at the other hint :D

Comment: Start by fixing the position of the pair 1 and 100.  Then position the other pairs relative to that one (since the arrangements are distinguished only  up to rotation).

Comment: @hardmath, Socrates in action! ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question states "arrangements that are rotations of each other count as the same" , you need to be a bit careful.

After fixing the 1-100 diameter,

there are only 49 pairs left to be *fixed and flipped*, yielding **$49!\cdot2^{49}$**

If you flip the 1-100 diameter too, you will be duplicating previous arrangements looked at (say) clockwise.

Answer (score -1):

For the sum of every opposing pair to be equal there will be only one potential partner for any given integer. How many ways can we arrange these fifty diameter pairs? Using circular permutation we know $49!$ is the number of ways we can arrange fifty items in a circle, but the pairs can be individually flipped. That means each potential flip doubles the possible configurations $2^{50}$

$49! \cdot 2^{50}$

Comment: if you think about it .. you cannot flip all 50 members because it will turn out to be the same circular permutaion,. so your solution could be comptete if we reduce the power of 50 to 49 .. what do you think ?

Comment: I see what you mean

Comment: At least It's half right. lol math humor.